# ask password inputed for sudo install command

Tags: software-installation, sudo, passwd

I had written a regular account name debian8 into sudoers file.

```
echo "debian8  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

To reboot and install some package.

```
sudo  dpkg -i Brackets*.deb
[sudo] password for debian8: 
Selecting previously unselected package brackets.
(Reading database ... 85361 files and directories currently installed.)
```

How to execute the command **sudo  dpkg -i Brackets*.deb** directly ,without asking to input password?

Why is no use to set  config as below?

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myRules
debian8   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I fix the problem with following method.

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
debian8   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Why is no use to edit in /etc/sudoers.d/myRules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never, **ever** run things like `echo something >>  /etc/sudoers`. One small typo, any kind of mistake, and you can break `sudo` on your system. You'll then have to boot into a live session, mount the local disk and undo what you broke. It's a pain to do and there are tools specifically esigned to help you avoid this sort of issue. So just always use `sudo visudo`. If you are not comfortable with the vim editor, you can use `nano` or any other editor instead by setting the `EDITOR` variable:

```
sudo EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano  visudo
```

Now, the first command you tried—the `echo`—although dangerous, should have worked. If it didn't, you probably ran something slightly different. Did you maybe run the command as `debian8` and not as `root`?

If you run `sudo visudo` and add this line, it will work as expected:

```
debian8  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And no need for reboot, just close `visudo`. As for why adding your rule to `/etc/sudoers.d/myRules` failed, that's because you also need to tell `sudoers` to include any files in that directory. On my Arch system, the relevant section is commented out:

```
$ sudo grep 'sudoers\.d' /etc/sudoers
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

So, to include rules set in `/etc/sudoers.d`, you need to run `sudo visudo` again and change (or insert) the above lines so they look like this:

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d
includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Very, very important advice from you : "Never, **ever** run things like echo something >>  /etc/sudoers." ! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably not be editing the /etc/sudoers file directly like that. Instead, either:

1.) use the command 'visudo' as root to edit the file 
2.) even better, add you config changes as overrides in a separate file as follows:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myRules
```

Now, enter the following line inside the text editor that opens:

```
debian8   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now, of course you can use Ctrl-O to write the file and then Ctrl-X to exit (if your visudo opens Nano, which mine does).

Hopefully this is helpful. Enjoy!